# How do you play a movie in an iphone app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, media-player, movie

I want to add a movie at the beginning of my iphone app. I have watched the tutorials and this is the code I have come up with. Why won't it work. I don't even see a movie. I call it from the viewDidLoad function of my ViewController with the following code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BTS Intro" ofType:@"mov"];
[self playMovieAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path

-(void)playMovieAtURL:(NSURL *)theURL {
MPMoviePlayerController *thePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:theURL];
thePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
thePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:thePlayer];
[thePlayer play];
}

-(void)myMovieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
MPMoviePlayerController *thePlayer = [aNotification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:thePlayer];
[thePlayer release];
}
```

Comment: Is the path definitely correct?  It is case-sensitive, so the movie needs to be in your project and named "BTS Intro.mov" exactly.

Answer (score 2):

You initiated playing of a movie but didn't add [thePlayer view] into views hierarchy that is why you do not see anything. Take a look at description of this operation in apple docs:

When you add a movie player’s view to your app’s view hierarchy, be sure to size the frame correctly, as shown here:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player =
        [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: myURL];
[player.view setFrame: myView.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
[myView addSubview: player.view];
// ...
[player play];
```

[MPMoviePlayerController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)